# Error escaping elisp regex

Tags: regular-expressions

```
 (string-match-p "^\(./\|../\)" "../lib/tern")
```

returns false.

What is the correct regex pattern to check if the string begins with `./` or `../`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of not enough escaping. You do need to escape dots (unescaped it means "any character just not the end of line"). When you escape anything in a string literal you need double slash.

A regular expression you want could be this:

```
(string-match-p "^\\.\\.?/" "../lib/tern")
```

Your original version could be rewritten like so:

```
(string-match-p "^\\(:?\\.\\|\\.\\.\\)/" "../lib/tern")
```